# Google Analytics API, Export Data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the Google Analytics API, is it possible to extract data about my visitors and display it on my website/application? I was not able to find if this is possible or not from the documentations...

For example, I would like to export data on my visitors such as their age/gender etc and display on my app.

Is this possible using the GA API?

Comment: This is certainly possible with the API in conjunction with some charting application (e.g. Google Visiualizations). Lots of steps and coding. If you want to avoid all the coding and employ a quick and easy approach, check out our widgets page at http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalytics-reporting-widgets.html (disclosure: I work with them). You basically authenticate against your GA account, create charts/widgets, and then embed in your site where you want them to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One low-level way is with the [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/), another good way is using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/spreadsheet-add-on/).

This [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_Ok0rJwj2U) explains how to use the Spreadsheet Add-on to create visualizations that can be embeded onto any website.